# Envio una solicitud ajax con un array de objetos, los cuales con tienen una llave de string con espacio y mi backend lo recibe sin espacios

Tags: php, laravel, json, laravel-5, php7

A mi backend envio un json como este:

```
[
  {
    "br": 2,
    "selectPrintMode": 0,
    "setColor": 0,
    "setDoubleStrike": false,
    "setEmphasis": true,
    "setFont": 0,
    "setJustification": 1,
    "setLineSpacing": 1,
    "setPrintLeftMargin": 0,
    "setPrintWidth": 576,
    "setReverseColors": false,
    "setTextSize": [
      1,
      1
    ],
    "setUnderline": 0,
    "text": "*** Vales ***"
  },
  {
    "br": 1,
    "selectPrintMode": 0,
    "setColor": 0,
    "setDoubleStrike": false,
    "setEmphasis": true,
    "setFont": 0,
    "setJustification": 1,
    "setLineSpacing": 1,
    "setPrintLeftMargin": 0,
    "setPrintWidth": 576,
    "setReverseColors": false,
    "setTextSize": [
      1,
      1
    ],
    "setUnderline": 0,
    "text": "Concepto       Observacion                 Monto"
  },
  {
    "br": 1,
    "selectPrintMode": 0,
    "setColor": 0,
    "setDoubleStrike": false,
    "setEmphasis": false,
    "setFont": 0,
    "setJustification": 0,
    "setLineSpacing": 1,
    "setPrintLeftMargin": 0,
    "setPrintWidth": 576,
    "setReverseColors": false,
    "setTextSize": [
      1,
      1
    ],
    "setUnderline": 0,
    "text": "restrooms    Esto tan solo es una               "
  },
  {
    "br": 1,
    "selectPrintMode": 0,
    "setColor": 0,
    "setDoubleStrike": false,
    "setEmphasis": false,
    "setFont": 0,
    "setJustification": 0,
    "setLineSpacing": 1,
    "setPrintLeftMargin": 0,
    "setPrintWidth": 576,
    "setReverseColors": false,
    "setTextSize": [
      1,
      1
    ],
    "setUnderline": 0,
    "text": "             prueba                             "
  },
  {
    "br": 1,
    "selectPrintMode": 0,
    "setColor": 0,
    "setDoubleStrike": false,
    "setEmphasis": false,
    "setFont": 0,
    "setJustification": 0,
    "setLineSpacing": 1,
    "setPrintLeftMargin": 0,
    "setPrintWidth": 576,
    "setReverseColors": false,
    "setTextSize": [
      1,
      1
    ],
    "setUnderline": 0,
    "text": "                                                "
  },
  {
    "br": 1,
    "selectPrintMode": 0,
    "setColor": 0,
    "setDoubleStrike": false,
    "setEmphasis": false,
    "setFont": 0,
    "setJustification": 0,
    "setLineSpacing": 1,
    "setPrintLeftMargin": 0,
    "setPrintWidth": 576,
    "setReverseColors": false,
    "setTextSize": [
      1,
      1
    ],
    "setUnderline": 0,
    "text": "                                                "
  },
  {
    "br": 1,
    "selectPrintMode": 0,
    "setColor": 0,
    "setDoubleStrike": false,
    "setEmphasis": false,
    "setFont": 0,
    "setJustification": 0,
    "setLineSpacing": 1,
    "setPrintLeftMargin": 0,
    "setPrintWidth": 576,
    "setReverseColors": false,
    "setTextSize": [
      1,
      1
    ],
    "setUnderline": 0,
    "text": "                                         9999.00"
  }
]
```

El problema es que cuando lo recibo en el backend obtengo las llaves **text** sin los espacios antes y despues del texto (como si estuviese haciendo un **trim**). ¿Alguien sabe como puedo evitar eso?

```
[
  {
    "br": "2",
    "selectPrintMode": "0",
    "setColor": "0",
    "setDoubleStrike": "false",
    "setEmphasis": "true",
    "setFont": "0",
    "setJustification": "1",
    "setLineSpacing": "1",
    "setPrintLeftMargin": "0",
    "setPrintWidth": "576",
    "setReverseColors": "false",
    "setTextSize": [
      "1",
      "1"
    ],
    "setUnderline": "0",
    "text": "*** Vales ***"
  },
  {
    "br": "1",
    "selectPrintMode": "0",
    "setColor": "0",
    "setDoubleStrike": "false",
    "setEmphasis": "true",
    "setFont": "0",
    "setJustification": "1",
    "setLineSpacing": "1",
    "setPrintLeftMargin": "0",
    "setPrintWidth": "576",
    "setReverseColors": "false",
    "setTextSize": [
      "1",
      "1"
    ],
    "setUnderline": "0",
    "text": "Concepto       Observacion                 Monto"
  },
  {
    "br": "1",
    "selectPrintMode": "0",
    "setColor": "0",
    "setDoubleStrike": "false",
    "setEmphasis": "false",
    "setFont": "0",
    "setJustification": "0",
    "setLineSpacing": "1",
    "setPrintLeftMargin": "0",
    "setPrintWidth": "576",
    "setReverseColors": "false",
    "setTextSize": [
      "1",
      "1"
    ],
    "setUnderline": "0",
    "text": "restrooms    Esto tan solo es una"
  },
  {
    "br": "1",
    "selectPrintMode": "0",
    "setColor": "0",
    "setDoubleStrike": "false",
    "setEmphasis": "false",
    "setFont": "0",
    "setJustification": "0",
    "setLineSpacing": "1",
    "setPrintLeftMargin": "0",
    "setPrintWidth": "576",
    "setReverseColors": "false",
    "setTextSize": [
      "1",
      "1"
    ],
    "setUnderline": "0",
    "text": "prueba"
  },
  {
    "br": "1",
    "selectPrintMode": "0",
    "setColor": "0",
    "setDoubleStrike": "false",
    "setEmphasis": "false",
    "setFont": "0",
    "setJustification": "0",
    "setLineSpacing": "1",
    "setPrintLeftMargin": "0",
    "setPrintWidth": "576",
    "setReverseColors": "false",
    "setTextSize": [
      "1",
      "1"
    ],
    "setUnderline": "0",
    "text": null
  },
  {
    "br": "1",
    "selectPrintMode": "0",
    "setColor": "0",
    "setDoubleStrike": "false",
    "setEmphasis": "false",
    "setFont": "0",
    "setJustification": "0",
    "setLineSpacing": "1",
    "setPrintLeftMargin": "0",
    "setPrintWidth": "576",
    "setReverseColors": "false",
    "setTextSize": [
      "1",
      "1"
    ],
    "setUnderline": "0",
    "text": null
  },
  {
    "br": "1",
    "selectPrintMode": "0",
    "setColor": "0",
    "setDoubleStrike": "false",
    "setEmphasis": "false",
    "setFont": "0",
    "setJustification": "0",
    "setLineSpacing": "1",
    "setPrintLeftMargin": "0",
    "setPrintWidth": "576",
    "setReverseColors": "false",
    "setTextSize": [
      "1",
      "1"
    ],
    "setUnderline": "0",
    "text": "9999.00"
  }
]
```

***Actualización 1:***

El backend lo manejo de esta manera. ¿Por que necesito los espacios? Es porque necesito imprimir en una impresora térmica la cual estoy ordenando los datos como si fuesen una tabla.

```
public function imprimir(Request $req) {
    try{
        $profile = CapabilityProfile::load("TM-T88IV");
        $connector = new NetworkPrintConnector($req['ip']);
        $printer = new Printer($connector, $profile);

        $lista = $req['lineas'];
        foreach ($lista as $key => $value) {
            $printer->selectPrintMode(intval($value['selectPrintMode']));
            $printer->setColor(intval($value['setColor']));
            $printer->setDoubleStrike(($value['setDoubleStrike']==='true')?true:false);
            $printer->setEmphasis(($value['setEmphasis']==='true')?true:false);
            $printer->setFont(intval($value['setFont']));
            $printer->setJustification(intval($value['setJustification']));
            $printer->setLineSpacing(intval($value['setLineSpacing']));
            $printer->setPrintLeftMargin(intval($value['setPrintLeftMargin']));
            $printer->setReverseColors(($value['setReverseColors']==='true')?true:false);
            $printer->setTextSize(intval($value['setTextSize'][0]),intval($value['setTextSize'][1]));
            $printer->setUnderline(intval($value['setUnderline']));
            $printer->text($value['text']);
        }

        $printer->feed();
        $printer->cut();
        $printer->close();
        return Response::json($req);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return Response::json($e);
    }
}
```

***Actualizacion 2:***

Los envío en una petición ajax de la siguiente manera:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    global: true,
    url: 'imprimir',
    data: datos, //acá va el json que envío.
}).then(
    function(data) {
        alertify.notify('Impreso correctamente','success');
    }, function(data) {
        console.log('this will run if the $.ajax fails');
        console.log('Error');
        console.log(data);
    }, function() {
        console.log('this will run if the deferred generates a progress update');
    }
);
```

Comment: ¿Qué manejo de los datos haces en el servidor? ¿En qué parte compruebas que los espacios son eliminados? Sin eso, es imposible poder saber qué está pasando realmente. Por favor, pon el código de servidor que recibe y maneja la respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano listo, hermano, ya lo actualice.

Comment: @PabloContreras como envías el json al BackEnd ??

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO alli edite la pregunta, colocando la manera en que lo envío.

Comment: @PabloContreras has esta prueba , utiliza JSON.stringify(datos) y me avisas si llega con los espacios para poner la respuesta

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO ¿como lo capturo en el backend?

Comment: @PabloContreras Hiciste la prueba ? , solo envialo como lo tienes pero le pones el Json.Stringify  asi `data: JSON.stringify(datos)`

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO si, ya lo hice, pero el request de laravel no me lo reconoce.

Comment: prueba de esta forma en el request  `$data = $request->json()->all();`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100249/discussion-between-francisco-j-blanco-and-pablo-contreras).

Answer (score 0):

El texto con los espacios en blanco pasalos por encodeURIComponent("   texto")

```
encodeURIComponent("Concepto       Observacion                 Monto")
```

Comment: ¿Tengo que hacer algo para que el backend reconozca el **%20** como un espacio?

Comment: urldecode($value['text'])